# How can I one hot encode a subset of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have a data set which has some categorical columns. Here is a small sample:

```
Temp    precip dow  tod
-20.44  snow   4    14.5
-22.69  snow   4    15.216666666666667
-21.52  snow   4    17.316666666666666
-21.52  snow   4    17.733333333333334
-20.51  snow   4    18.15
```

Here, the `dow` and `precip` are categorical, where as the others are continuous.

Is there a way I can create a `OneHotEncoder` for just those columns?  I don't want to use `pd.get_dummies` because that won't put the data in the proper format unless of each `dow` and `precip` are in the new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to use `pd.get_dummies` because that won't put the data in
>   the proper format unless of each dow and precip are in the new data.

Assuming you want to encode but also maintain those two columns--are you sure this wouldn't work for you?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'temp': np.random.random(5) + 20.,
    'precip': pd.Categorical(['snow', 'snow', 'rain', 'none', 'rain']),
    'dow': pd.Categorical([4, 4, 4, 3, 1]),
    'tod': np.random.random(5) + 10.
    })

pd.concat((df[['dow', 'precip']],
          pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['dow', 'precip'], drop_first=True)),
          axis=1)

  dow precip     temp      tod  dow_3  dow_4  precip_rain  precip_snow
0   4   snow  20.7019  10.4610      0      1            0            1
1   4   snow  20.0917  10.0174      0      1            0            1
2   4   rain  20.3978  10.5766      0      1            1            0
3   3   none  20.9804  10.0770      1      0            0            0
4   1   rain  20.3121  10.3584      0      0            1            0
```

In the case where you'll be interacting with new data that includes categories that `df` hasn't "seen," you can use

```
df['col'] = df['col'].cat.add_categories(...)
```

Where you pass a list of the set difference.  This adds to the list of "recognized" categories for the resulting `pd.Categorical` object.

Answer (score 4):

Two things you could check out: [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas) and as mentioned by @Grr [pipelines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) with this good [intro](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html).

So I prefer pipelines, as they are a tidy way, allow easy use with things like grid-seach, avoid leakage between folds in cross validation, etc. So I usually end up having a pipe like that (given you have precip LabelEncoded first):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion, make_pipeline, make_union
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

class Columns(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, names=None):
        self.names = names

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.names]

class Normalize(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, func=None, func_param={}):
        self.func = func
        self.func_param = func_param

    def transform(self, X):
        if self.func != None:
            return self.func(X, **self.func_param)
        else:
            return X

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self


cat_cols = ['precip', 'dow']
num_cols = ['Temp','tod']

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("features", FeatureUnion([
        ('numeric', make_pipeline(Columns(names=num_cols),Normalize())),
        ('categorical', make_pipeline(Columns(names=cat_cols),OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)))
    ])),
    ('model', LinearRegression())
])
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, but with some caveats.

First off you won't be able to use [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) directly on the `precip` feature. You will need to encode those labels in to integers with [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder).

Secondly, if you just want to encode those features you can pass the proper values to the `n_values` and `categorical_features` parameters.

Example:

I will assume `dow` is day of the week, which will have seven values, and precip will have (rain, sleet, snow, and mix) as values.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

df2 = df.copy()

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['rain', 'sleet', 'snow', 'mix'])
df2.precip = le.transform(df2.precip)
df2
    Temp  precip  dow        tod
0 -20.44       3    4  14.500000
1 -22.69       3    4  15.216667
2 -21.52       3    4  17.316667
3 -21.52       3    4  17.733333
4 -20.51       3    4  18.150000

# Initialize OneHotEncoder with 4 values for precip and 7 for dow.
ohe = OneHotEncoder(n_values=np.array([4,7]), categorical_features=[1,2])
X = ohe.fit_transform(df2)
X.toarray()
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -20.44      ,  14.5       ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -22.69      ,
         15.21666667],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -21.52      ,
         17.31666667],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -21.52      ,
         17.73333333],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -20.51      ,  18.15      ]])
```

Ok that works, but you have to either mutate your data in place or create a copy an things can get a little messy. A more organized way to do this would be to use a [`Pipeline`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline

def get_precip(X):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(['rain', 'sleet', 'snow', 'mix'])
    return le.transform(X.precip).reshape(-1,1)

def get_dow(X):
    return X.dow.values.reshape(-1,1)

def get_rest(X):
    return X.drop(['precip', 'dow'], axis=1)

precip_trans = FunctionTransformer(get_precip, validate=False)
dow_trans = FunctionTransformer(get_dow, validate=False)
rest_trans = FunctionTransformer(get_rest, validate=False)
union = FeatureUnion([('precip', precip_trans), ('dow', dow_trans), ('rest', rest_trans)])
ohe = OneHotEncoder(n_values=[4,7], categorical_features=[0,1])
pipe = Pipeline([('union', union), ('one_hot', ohe)])
X = pipe.fit_transform(df)
X.toarray()
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -20.44      ,  14.5       ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -22.69      ,
         15.21666667],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -21.52      ,
         17.31666667],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -21.52      ,
         17.73333333],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -20.51      ,  18.15      ]])
```

I do want to point out that in the upcoming release of sklearn v0.20 there will be a [`CategoricalEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html) which should make this kind of thing even easier.